# Pandas manupulation: Non-distinct groups

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
Time    c_1     c_2   
 t1      x       1
 t2      x       2
 t3      y       1
 t4      y       2
 t5      1       x
 t6      2       x
 t7      1       y
 t8      2       y
```

I need to form 2 columns without looping, such that:

- new_1: Next earliest Time that c_1.value appear in c_2 (eg. For t1, new_1 = t5, because c_1 value is 'x', and the next time 'x' appears in c_2 is at t5)
- new_2: Next earliest Time that c_2.value appear in c_1 (eg. For t1, new_1 = t5, because c_2 value is '1', and the next time '1' appears in c_1 is at t3)

So for the above input, the output should be:

```
Time    c_1     c_2    new_1     new_2
 t1      x       1       t5        t5
 t2      x       2       t5        t6
 t3      y       1       t7        t5            
 t4      y       2       t7        t6      
 t5      1       x       NaT       NaT
 t6      2       x       NaT       NaT
 t7      1       y       NaT       NaT
 t8      2       y       NaT       NaT
```

How would you approach this?

Comment: Please show exactly the `DataFrame` you expect to get as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `apply()` and a lambda function to select the correct data from the original DataFrame for each row.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Time': pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=16, freq='D'),
        'c_1': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', '1', '2', '1', '2']*2,
        'c_2': ['1', '2', '1', '2', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y']*2 }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)    
df['new_1'] = df.apply(lambda r: (df.Time[(df.Time>r.Time) & (df.c_2 == r.c_1)].head(1).reset_index(drop=True)), axis=1)
df['new_2'] = df.apply(lambda r: (df.Time[(df.Time>r.Time) & (df.c_1 == r.c_2)].head(1).reset_index(drop=True)), axis=1)
print(df)
```

The output is:

```
         Time c_1 c_2      new_1      new_2
0  2000-01-01   x   1 2000-01-05 2000-01-05
1  2000-01-02   x   2 2000-01-05 2000-01-06
2  2000-01-03   y   1 2000-01-07 2000-01-05
3  2000-01-04   y   2 2000-01-07 2000-01-06
4  2000-01-05   1   x 2000-01-09 2000-01-09
5  2000-01-06   2   x 2000-01-10 2000-01-09
6  2000-01-07   1   y 2000-01-09 2000-01-11
7  2000-01-08   2   y 2000-01-10 2000-01-11
8  2000-01-09   x   1 2000-01-13 2000-01-13
9  2000-01-10   x   2 2000-01-13 2000-01-14
10 2000-01-11   y   1 2000-01-15 2000-01-13
11 2000-01-12   y   2 2000-01-15 2000-01-14
12 2000-01-13   1   x        NaT        NaT
13 2000-01-14   2   x        NaT        NaT
14 2000-01-15   1   y        NaT        NaT
15 2000-01-16   2   y        NaT        NaT
```

The `apply` is done with `axis=1` so it iterates one row at a time. The lambda function selects only rows of the dataframe that occur after the current row and that have the correct values in the columns. There may be multiple rows that match these conditions. The `head(1)` selects the first match and the `reset_index(drop=True)` ensures that each Series returned has the same index (0), so that `apply()` places them all off the return values into a single column.

Comment: is there a way to generalize this? If we expand you solution to 16 periods, with the values repeating itself, only the top 4 dates will be populated with your solution.

Comment: @Yeile I couldn't generalize the `groupby` version, but I came up with a version that uses `apply` and addresses repeating values in a general way.